# Torch, is there any Gaussian function module?

Tags: probability, torch, activation

I've to implement a [probabilistic neural network](https://www.cse.unr.edu/~looney/cs773b/PNNtutorial.pdf) in Torch.

To do that, I need to have a module that implements a Gaussian function module. I would need something like `nn.Gaussian()` but it does not exist.

How could I use this function as a module?
Do you know any implementation of a Gaussian as a module?

Answer (score 1):

Could [this package](http://deepmind.github.io/torch-distributions/#toc_9) from DeepMind help you?

Usage:

```
th> require 'distributions'
th> distributions.norm.pdf(1.96, 0, 1)
0.058440944333451
```

Comment: Thanks David Khosid. I works as a Gaussian, but I don't know how to use it as an activation function module in `nn`. Do you have any suggestion?